# Angular2 Server Side Rendering - Angular 2 Universal Issue

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-universal

I tried changing my angular2 app to angular2 universal. On that I segregated server and client side module. On doing npm start I am getting the following error.

```
EXCEPTION: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
Error: The selector "app-root" did not match any elements
    at DomRenderer.selectRootElement (C:\Users\SYS168\scotchiversal - Copy\dist\server\index.js:26663:23)
    at selectOrCreateRenderHostElement (C:\Users\SYS168\scotchiversal - Copy\dist\server\index.js:15131:32)
    at AppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.createInternal (/AppModule/AppComponent/host.ngfactory.js:12:16)
    at AppView.create (C:\Users\SYS168\scotchiversal - Copy\dist\server\index.js:51125:21)
    at ComponentFactory.create (C:\Users\SYS168\scotchiversal - Copy\dist\server\index.js:36104:36)
    at ApplicationRef_.bootstrap (C:\Users\SYS168\scotchiversal - Copy\dist\server\index.js:22794:40)
    at C:\Users\SYS168\scotchiversal - Copy\dist\server\index.js:22703:89
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at PlatformRef_._moduleDoBootstrap (C:\Users\SYS168\scotchiversal - Copy\dist\server\index.js:22703:42)
    at C:\Users\SYS168\scotchiversal - Copy\dist\server\index.js:22671:27
```

Can you please somebody help me out.
This is my folder structure https://s11.postimg.org/g5xht8k6b/git.png

[My folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IIwF.png)

Comment: Have u checked whether you are using the same selector name in your Root component and your main html page

Comment: Yes I checked same only. Actually website is loading I mean client side rendering but not server side. @ViChU